# How split data of a field grab data from different columns put relevant data into a group using ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have table jobs. Columns are:

```
jobid    | title           |   vens   |  clts | positions 
---------| ----------------|--------------------------------    
2013     | Dog walker      |  -1,2-   |  1    |  1    
2015     | Cook  -------   | - 1 - -  |  1    |  3      
1156     | House Keep      |   1,2,3  |  1    |  2    
1832     | Lawn Cleaner    |  -- 3-   |  1    |  1    
1923     | Gardener        |  2,3     |  2    |  3
```

---

Now I want to make a report builder report in sql server reporting services using client id. I want to show results as below.

clts :1 onclick of view report

```
vens | jobid | title        | positions
1    | 2013  | DOG WALKER   | 1
1    | 2015  | Cook         | 3
1    | 1156  | House Keep   | 2
2    | 2013  | DOG WALKER   | 1
2    | 1156  | House Keep   | 2
3    | 1156  | House Keep   | 2
3    | 1832  | Lawn cleaner | 1
```

Can someone help please? Sorry for bad appearance of table design.

Comment: The `vens` column on the `jobs` table should not store comma separated data. You need to pivot or split that to get what you are looking for.

Comment: You are much better-off creating a scheduled process or trigger to normalize the data in your [vens] column into another table.  Your entire solution would become much easier.

Comment: Thank you Parfait for editing and make it look beautifull